# HTML Tables Floating Down

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

https://eportal.enlinx.com/test/rates.php
is a web tool I'm building, but I'm having trouble getting the display to work out correctly.
I want the three columns to show the tables right under the bottom borders of the header-looking pieces. The idea is to have tables of two columns in each of those three main columns, because results for each shipping method will be displayed in the column to the right of the type name.
What's weird is it looks like the tables are floating down in distances proportional to the number of rows in the table?

Here's the HTML and CSS files:

(HTML):

```
<?php 
    include 'rates_header.php';

    // Rates Calculation Call


?>

            <!-- Header-type bar for freight calculation input -->
            <div id="inputBar">
                <!-- Warehouse List -- JUST Salt Lake City for now (store as address) -->
                <span>
                    <p>Warehouse</p>
                    <select>
                        <option id="warehouse">Enlinx -- Salt Lake City</option>
                    </select>
                </span>

                <!-- Country >> Fill by database query? * Choose one default country for now! -->
                <span>
                    <p>Country</p>
                    <select>
                        <option id="country">US</option>
                    </select>
                </span>

                <!-- City -->
                <span>
                    <p>City</p>
                    <input id="city" type="text" value="Seattle" />
                </span>

                <!-- State -->
                <span>
                    <p>State</p>
                    <select>
                        <option id="state">WA</option>
                    </select>
                </span>

                <!-- Zipcode of Destination -->
                <span>
                    <p>Zip</p>
                    <input type="text" id="zipcode" value="98115" />
                </span>

                <!-- Weight of Package -->
                <span>
                    <p>Weight</p>
                    <input type="text" id="weight" value="2.00" />
                </span>

                <!-- Method -->
                <span>
                    <p>Method</p>
                    <select>
                        <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
                        <option value="residential">Residential</option>
                    </select>
                </span>

                <!-- Dimensions -->
                <span>
                    <p>Dimensions in inches (LxWxH)</p>
                    <input type="text" id="length" /> x <input type="text" id="width" /> x <input type="text" id="height" />
                </span>
            </div>

            <!-- Freight Results Body && Shipping-type selection -->
            <div id="freightBody">

                <div id="FedExDiv">
                    <span class='caption'>
                        <h3>FedEx</h3>
                    </span>
                    <table> <!--... Third Party Billing options LEFT OUT -- what do with? -->
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx 2Day Commercial</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedEx2DayCommercialResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx 2Day Residential</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedEx2DayResidentialResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx 2Day</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedEx2DayResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Economy Puerto Rico Collect</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExEconomyPuertoRicoCollectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Economy Puerto Rico Pre-Paid</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExEconomyPuertoRicoPre-PaidResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Express Saver</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExExpressSaverResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Ground</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExGroundResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx International Collect</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExInternationalCollectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx International Economy</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExInternationalEconomyResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx International Pre-Paid</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExInternationalPre-PaidResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx International Priority</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExInternationalPriorityResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Priority Overnight</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExPriorityOvernightResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Priority Puerto Rico Collect</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExPriorityPuertoRicoCollectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Priority Puerto Rico Pre-Paid</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExPriorityPuertoRicoPre-PaidResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Saturday Priority</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExSaturdayPriorityResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx SmartPost</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExSmartPostResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>FedEx Standard Overnight</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='FedExStandardOvernightResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="UPSDiv">
                    <span class='caption'>
                        <h3>UPS</h3>
                    </span>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS 2nd Day Air</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPS2ndDayAirResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS 2nd Day Air Puerto Rico</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPS2ndDayAirPuertoRicoResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS 3Day Select</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPS3DaySelectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Ground</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSGroundResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Ground Residential</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSGroundResidentialResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS International</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSInternationalCollectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS International Pre-Paid</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSInternationalPre-PaidResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Next Day Air</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSNextDayAirResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Next Day Air Saver</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSNextDayAirSaverResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Worldwide Expedited</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSWorldwideExpeditedResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Worldwide Express</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSWorldwideExpressResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Worldwide Express Collect</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSWorldwideExpressCollectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Worldwide Express Plus</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSWorldwideExpressPlusResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Worldwide Express Plus Collect</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSWorldwideExpressPlusCollectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Worldwide Saver</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSWorldwideSaverResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='service'>UPS Worldwide Saver Collect</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='UPSWorldwideSaverCollectResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                    </table>
                    <input id='calculateButton' class='button' type='button' value='Save Money!' />
                </div>

                <!-- jQuery: Handle button -->
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {

                        $('#calculateButton').click(function() {

                            var input = [];
                            var service_class = document.getElementsByClassName('service');

                            // Get the shipment info
                            input[0] = 'ARIIX';
                            input[1] = $('#country').val();
                            input[2] = $('#state').val();
                            input[3] = $('#city').val();
                            input[4] = $('#zipcode').val();
                            input[5] = $('#weight').val();


                            // Grab all the service types
                            for(var i = 0; i < service_class.length; i++)
                                input.push(service_class[i].innerText);

                            console.log(input);

                            // AJAX POST back to this page with the results of the freight request
                            /*
                            $.post("calc.php", {input: input}, function(data) {

                                //var response = JSON.parse(data);

                                //alert(data.indexOf('<ERROR>'));

                                // Make sure valid values were entered for all fields!
                                if (data.indexOf('<ERROR>') != -1)
                                    alert(data);
                                else
                                {
                                    alert(data);
                                    //console.log(response);
                                }

                                //$('#UPSWorldwideSaverCollectResult').append(data);
                            });
                            */
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: "calc.php",
                                data: {input: input},
                                success: function(data) {

                                    //var response = JSON.parse(data);
                                    //alert(response[0].valueOf());
                                    console.log(data);
                                    alert(data);
                                },
                                failure: function(data) {
                                    alert(data);
                                }
                            });



                        });
                    }); 

                </script>

                <div id="USPSDiv">
                        <span class='caption'>
                        <h3>USPS</h3>
                    </span>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="service">USPS Best Way Cost</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='USPSBestWayCostResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="service">USPS Express Mail</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='USPSExpressMailResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="service">USPS First Class Mail</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='USPSFirstClassMailResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="service">USPS Media Mail</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='USPSMediaMailResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="service">USPS Parcel Post Mail</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='USPSParcelPostMailResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class="service">USPS Priority Mail</span></th>
                            <th><span class='result' id='USPSPriorityMailResult'></span></th>
                        </tr><br />
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

(CSS):

```
#container
{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.header
{
position: relative;
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
}
#logo
{
position: relative;
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
background: white url('logo.png') no-repeat center;
background-size: 100%;
}


.Body
{
display: table;
position: absolute;
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
background-color:Gainsboro;
}
#inputBar
{
border-top: 2px solid;
border-bottom: 2px solid;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: DarkGray;
}
#freightBody
{
height: 95%;
width: 100%;
font-size: 115%;
background-color: Gainsboro;
}

#FedExDiv
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 32%;
margin-left: 1%;
background-color: blue;
}
#UPSDiv
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 32%;
margin-left: 1%;
}
#USPSDiv
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 32%;
margin-left: 1%;
}

span
{
display:table;
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-left: 1%;
text-align: center;
}
.service { background-color:red;    }
.result { height: 5%; width: 10%; background-color: white;  }

.row
{
height: 5%;
width: 35%;
}

{
font-weight: bold;
}
.button
{
width:20%;
height: 10%;
margin: 0 25% 0 25%;
}

.caption
{
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 120%;
border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

I've been sitting and looking through my CSS for the last half-hour or so and trying to Google for some related, but so far I've got nothing and I can't see what I've done wrong.

Any ideas?

NOTE: I forgot to mention - the HTML and BODY tags and DOC COMMENT are in the header/footer PHP files being included. Probably obvious but I just wanted to make sure I mentioned that.

Comment: post on jsfiddle.net pls

Comment: `<br>`s are not needed in a table. And `<th>` is meant for header cells only, not for normal cells. Use CSS to achieve the required style, not unsemantic HTML.

Comment: Oh gosh -- it was indeed the breaks.
I can't believe it was something so simple.
Thank you, very much!

Comment: You have some invalid HTML:  paragraphs aren't allowed inside `span` tags.  Use `div`s instead (or better yet, `label` instead of `p`)